# Installing java 1.4 on ubuntu 11.0

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

How do I install java 1.4 on ubuntu 11.0?

When I type java -version, it lists out packages from java 6  and 7. On the sun website I can only see solaris installers for 1.4.2.

Comment: Do you need 1.4 or 1.4.2?

Comment: our entire code base is in java 1.4. I'm trying to get it to work on ubuntu. As far as I know it's not going to work on 1.7

Comment: @Arun Have you tried with 1.7?

Comment: It might need some minor changes to compile on Java 7, but it might not.

Comment: As @PeterLawrey said you can use Oracle's website to download legacy Java versions. However, it may be worth looking into updating your code base. It may be a pretty big job but worth it in the long run if you intend to maintain the code.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did it get working with java 7. So far it is running with no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons only the OpenJDK is immediately available through the package system.

If you need an elder version of Sun Java (bought by Oracle), you need to download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html, unpack it yourself, and update your $PATH to point to it.  Possibly also your $JAVA_HOME for some tooling.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Oracle web site. It has every update from Java 1.1 and later. I use the tar.gz rather than the RPM.

Converting the code to be Java 7 best practices is a big job, but just getting it to compile in Java 7 should be much simpler. e.g. you can't have variables/fields called `enum`  Some IDEs e.g. IntelliJ have migration tools to help you do both.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have hard control over versions of packages I recommend considering working with Gentoo. It may be daunting or even intimidating, but the package manager system gives you a LOT of control over specific versions. Working with Ubuntu over the years I have found it to be very challenging. I still have had no luck using an earlier version of Amarok in ubuntu.